# Register IStartupFilter with TryAddSingleton equivalent in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, asp.net-core-5.0

My class library registers an `IStartupFilter` (using a factory) with the ASP.NET Core container:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IStartupFilter>(serviceProvider => 
  ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyStartupFilter>(serviceProvider, new object[] { arg1, arg2 }));
```

That works.

But there are multiple ways to register the class library, so I don't want the filter to be added multiple times.

- If I use `AddSingleton` then the service is added, but could be added multiple times.
- If I use `TryAddSingleton` then the service is not added at all - because the runtime already registers an `IStartupFilter` of its own (`HostFilteringStartupFilter`)

How can I "try add" a startup filter that uses a factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dirty way to do it. If there's a better way please post your answer and I'll accept it.

```cs
var alreadyRegistered = services.Any(sd => 
  sd.ServiceType == typeof(IStartupFilter) &&
  sd.ImplementationFactory?.Target?.GetType() == this.GetType()
);

if (!alreadyRegistered)
{
  services.AddSingleton<IStartupFilter>(serviceProvider => 
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyStartupFilter>(serviceProvider, new object[] { arg1, arg2 }));
}
```

This fiddles with the service collection, which is an implementation detail of the container that should be left alone. And it assumes that the check and the registration occur in the same class. And it does not actually specify `MyStartupFilter`, so you're not even sure it's doing the right thing, especially if that class adds other startup filters.

Dirty but works in simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

you could add

```
services.RemoveAll<IStartupFilter>();
```

before your codes

also,you could try the method in ServiceCollectionDescriptorExtensions class:

```
public static IServiceCollection Replace(this IServiceCollection collection, ServiceDescriptor descriptor);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: For `RemoveAll` - it will remove other startup filters added by the framework, so it won't work. For `Replace` - I'm using an implementation **factory**, so in my case it doesn't help, but, for people who must replace a service by implementation **type** or **instance**, it is a good solution. Thanks!